# Can I tell clients that I have resigned?

Tags: resignation

So it's 3 days before my last day working in my current company. I have complied with company policy that resignation should be handled at least 1 month before. Strange thing that I noticed is that when I asked how the project turn over should be handled, the boss said that only the projects that I handled alone (alone as in I'm the only one from our company that handles it, doesn't necssarily means totally alone since we have a freelance programmer for that project) that should be briefed to other guys. For other projects I need not to do a thing.

Now, my position in the company is the manager/supervisor in an IT company. I'm not clear which one, since sometimes the boss would address me as the manager, the other time the supervisor.

Another strange thing that I noticed is that apart from my boss and the HRD, no one else knows that I have submitted my resignation. Not even the other supervisor, that I suppose would have to handle the projects on my leave.

The problem is that many of the projects are overdue thanks to the constant turnover of programmers. Constant as in at least 1 programmer a month. My boss has used, "the programmer ran away" as an excuse for a late project to some clients before. I'm afraid that he is setting me up so that I would take the blame since both my boss and the hrd are keeping the information of my resignation for themselves.

The boss has previously accussed me of "deliberately messing up" a project. Indeed I messed that up, but I didn't do that deliberately. I already told him many times that I have too much projects under me. But he always said that, "you're the supervisor/manager, who else should handle it other than you?" In other words he kept using my position as an excuse to push more responsibilities and work, which is why I quit.

Should I inform the clients that I have resigned, so I can avoid being used as the black sheep for the overdue projects? Is it legal and ethical for me to do so? I'm afraid if I don't then the acussation would affect my chance to land a new job in the future. Who would want to hire someone who ran away, right? But can I be sued for announcing my resignation to clients?

Comment: Have you asked your boss about why nobody knows you are leaving and whether you are allowed to tell anyone? Then at least you'd know about their plans.

Comment: And if they indeed planned to put the blame on me, why would they admit it as their plan?

Answer (score 5):

> Can I tell clients that I have resigned?

Not a good idea, they're not your clients, they're your soon-to-be-former companies clients and it's up to their people who handle client relations to tell (or not).

There are things you should do dependent on what comes next in your career. If you have another job lined up then just move into that without creating drama.

If you're going in to business for yourself, then keep your ear to the ground, it's quite possible that everything will fall to bits between your old company and their clients and you may be able to get them assuming they like your work.

I would discount advice like it will look like you ran away. When a person resigns it could be a disgruntled employee or a disgruntled company mouthing off about the cause. Experienced people know this and discount most of that sort of stuff, personally if a company gave me an excuse 'their dev ran away' I wouldn't care about or blame the developer, I'm not employing the chap. I'm paying the company to sort their own problems out not bring their issues to me. The onus would sit squarely on the company as far as I'm concerned and if it caused me serious problems, I'd rip them a new orifice.

My advice is that once you have your foot out the door, focus on where your career is heading, not where it's been.

Comment: "Experienced people know this and discount most of that sort of stuff"  that bit is absolutely true.  I've had suppliers / subcontractors throw their own people under the bus often enough that it's pretty much standard operating procedure when something is going sideways.   People that have been around know this and ignore it as nothing more than noise.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must not inform the clients directly or fomally, that is the responsibility of your company. In many contracts there are clauses which says that any manpower attrition would be back-filled by the company if it is T&M and if fixed-bid, client simply need not know. One guess as to why your resignation is being kept from the client could be that it would be used by your supervisor to get project timeline extension (only a possibility).

In one circumstance you could informally inform the client manager, if you are at very cordial terms, you could make a phone call 1:1 and have an informal chat and mention that day after tomorrow is your last working day here. This only if you have very good terms with the client manager and you feel that you could seriously get a job there in sometime.